# How to start embedded ActiveMQ broker through gradle

Tags: gradle, activemq-classic, build.gradle, gradlew

I am writing integration test and i want to connect activeMQ broker. So far the strategy I am using ActiveMQ broker in gradle as dependency

```
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.14.5'
```

And In my configuration.xml file I am using

```
<bean id="inputActiveMqConnectionFactory" 
 class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="brokerURL">
        <value>vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="userName">
        <value>${active.mq.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${active.mq.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This connects to ActiveMQ broker and starts. I want to do apply same thing in build.gradle file and ActiveMQ should start when i run gradle build. How this can be achieved ?

Comment: Gradle is a build tool, It can only resolve/compile your dependencies and build project for you